# While loop condition issue with checking length

Tags: powershell

First of all, I'd like to point out I'm new at programming powershell, and programming in general, learnt most of it on my own so what seems complicated to me might end up being the easiest thing for you all.

Don't mind the google ping in my script as its only for testing purposes it will later be applied to another script i'm working on.

```
$ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '
$ComputerLength = $ComputerInput.Length -ge 13 -and $ComputerInput.Length -le 15

while ($ComputerLength -eq $false)
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Name invalid try again"
    $ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '    
}

ping google.ca -4
```

Currently if I run this its asking for a computer name and then goes directly to the ping without going through the `while` loop it seems like

I'm not 100% certain but I think my issue has to do with both

```
$ComputerLength = $ComputerInput.Length -ge 13 -and $ComputerInput.Length -le 15
```

and

```
while ($ComputerLength -eq $false)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It enters the `while` loop for me, if length of `$ComputerInput` is less than 13 or greater than 15. The problem actually is, that the `while` loop is never left again. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You a right, for some reason in visual studio it was bugging out, straight copied in powershell it works and does the same thing as you, it never leave the while loop. I'm wondering why thought since the length of what I input is ok, it would technically return as true and should leave no?

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison logic is fine - but you need to *re-calculate* the condition inside the loop - otherwise it'll stay `$false` and the loop will continue endlessly:

```
$ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '

# One option is to just execute the comparison operations inside the condition block
while (-not($ComputerInput.Length -ge 13 -and $ComputerInput.Length -le 15))
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Name invalid try again"
    $ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '    
}
```

Or, if you prefer storing the comparison result in a variable:

```
$ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '
$CorrectLength = $ComputerInput.Length -ge 13 -and $ComputerInput.Length -le 15

while (-not $CorrectLength)
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Name invalid try again"
    $ComputerInput = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name: '
    # Remember to re-calculate
    $CorrectLength = $ComputerInput.Length -ge 13 -and $ComputerInput.Length -le 15
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much, it was probably simple for you but you actually made me understand my mistake. Like I said, I am a newbie in powershell programming and this is really great. Thanks again it worked!